# Add mat-option conditionally to mat-select

Tags: angular, angular-material, hidden, angular-ng-if, mat-select

Remove some parameters inside a mat-select

Hi everyone! I'm bringing some parameters (7) from a database but I only need to work with 4, so that when displaying the list of the mat-select it shows me only the 4, not 7. I have tried to hide them with the [hidden] option but I really want to remove them and my browser doesn't see them, how could I do it? I am quite a newbie to Angular. I have read that with an * ngIf but I don't know how. I appreciate any help!

**HTML:**

```html
<td>
  <mat-select
    placeholder="Tipo trámite"
    name="tipoTramite"
    [(ngModel)]="tipoTramiteValue"
    (change)="onChange(tipoTramiteValue)"
  >
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let tipoTramite of listTiposNovedad"
      [value]="tipoTramite.nombreParametro"
      [hidden]="tipoTramite.nombreParametro == 'TERMINACIÓN ANTICIPADA' || tipoTramite.nombreParametro == 'PRÓRROGA'  || tipoTramite.nombreParametro == 'SUSPENSIÓN'"
      >{{tipoTramite.nombreParametro}}</mat-option
    >
  </mat-select>
</td>
```

**TS:**

```js
export class SolicitudFormat implements OnInit {
  tipoNovedad;
  listTiposNovedad;

  constructor(
    private dialog: MatDialog,
    public datePipe: DatePipe,
    public adminCTService: AdminCtserviceService,
    public parametroService: ParametroService
  ) {
    this.parametroService.listNovedadesContrato().subscribe((response) => {
      this.listTiposNovedad = response;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using *ngIf this way

*ngIf="condition" (where condition is the condition on which you want to render the element)

```
<td>
          <mat-select placeholder="Tipo trámite" name="tipoTramite" [(ngModel)]="tipoTramiteValue"  (change)="onChange(tipoTramiteValue)">
<ng-container *ngFor="let tipoTramite of listTiposNovedad">
            <mat-option *ngIf="!(tipoTramite.nombreParametro == 'TERMINACIÓN ANTICIPADA' || tipoTramite.nombreParametro == 'PRÓRROGA'  || tipoTramite.nombreParametro == 'SUSPENSIÓN')" [value]="tipoTramite.nombreParametro" >{{tipoTramite.nombreParametro}}</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
<ng-container>
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Shyam Joshi !! Your solution could solve my problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Aragorn8806 Glad to know, it could help you. Happy coding... :)